# SSIS Package not visible to other users or on saved location

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, ssis, sql-server-2012

I'm using Visual Studio 2012 \ SSIS:
[image]

I have a Project with 94 dtsx files in.  However, a few things have occurred that I do not understand and was wondering if anyone can help.

1. Of these 94, only 84 are visible as dtsx files in the network folder where they are saving.  Even if I right click on one of the 10 'missing' ones, go to properties and file path, copy this address into Windows Explorer, the actual dtsx file is not there but continues to show in Visual Studio
2. Of these 94 if another user opens the project, they can only see 84
3. If I deploy to the SSIS catalog, ALL 94 are there

Is there a way to 'refresh' the packages etc?  I have right clicked on the project and choose Build, but this has not fixed it.

Comment: Opening a (Visual Studio) project on the network is rarely a good idea. Store the project locally, and use source control to share the project with the rest of the team and include it in back up strategies.

Comment: thanks @Larnu but this is a corporate decision that I am afraid I can not change easily

Comment: I would suggest pushing to do so then. Source Control and local development environments are a most for good team project building.